# How add one list with item of a specific keys of a dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of words (`listwords = ['a', 'b', 'c']`) and a previously original dict (`dictwords = {'111': '['a', 'a', 'b']', '112': '['b', 'a', 'b']'}`) whose purpose is to create a new dict where the keys will be the listwords and their elements will be the quantity one. extra identification and how many words occur in the original dict. The code looks like this:

```
for i in listwords:
        addlist= []
        for k, x in dictwords.items():
            if i in x:
                cont = 0
                cont = x.count(i)
                addlist.append(k)
                addlist.append(cont)
                newdict[i] = addlist
```

The end result should be this below:

```
a ->  ['111', 2], ['112', 1]
b ->  ['111', 2], ['112', 1]
c ->  ['111', 0], ['112', 0]
```

i.e. it was supposed to be a key with its respective count lists in the new dict, but the result that is coming out is this:

```
a ->  ['111', 2, '112', 1]
b ->  ['111', 2, '112', 1]
c ->  ['111', 0, '112', 0]
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Should I insert a new list and thus insert in the new dict?

Comment: So what exactly is the format you're looking for? Do you want a lists of list (e.g. `[['111', 2], ['112', 1]]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to iterate over the subarrays, your `.count` does that for you. Instead, loop over the keys in `listwords` so that you don't have to check multiple times for the same character.

Try this instead:

```
for i in listwords:
        addlist= []
        for k, x in dictwords.items():
            addlist.append({k: x.count(i)})
        newdict[i] = addlist
```

---

```
>>> newdict
{'a': [{'111': 2}, {'112': 1}], 'b': [{'111': 1}, {'112': 2}], 'c': [{'111': 0}, {'112': 0}]}
```

You can also use a simple list/dict comprehension to accomplish your goals:

```
>>> {i: [{key: dictwords[key].count(i)} for key in dictwords] for i in listwords}
{'a': [{'111': 2}, {'112': 1}], 'b': [{'111': 1}, {'112': 2}], 'c': [{'111': 0}, {'112': 0}]}
```

Comment: Nice one liner. Glad you added the more extended method though, as the one liner may be a bit much for a beginner.

Comment: @ChristianDean i'm a big fan of comprehensions, but sometimes they do sacrifice readability :) Always good to provide both sides of the coin.

Comment: Yep, that's true. I'm a sucker for a good one-liner, but sometimes using an extended method is better for documentation purposes :-) @A.J. Uppal

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Should I insert a new list and thus insert in the new dict?

You don't need to insert a new list per se, you just need to change where you're initializing `addlist`. Assuming you want a list of lists, you need to initialize `addlist` for every key in `dictwords`. That means moving `addlist = []` under `for k, x in dictwords.items():`.

Now, instead of assigning `addlist` to a key in `newdict`, you need to have `newdict` create a list for each letter in `listwords` and *append* `addlist` to the list for each letter. There are a couple of different ways to do this, but a pretty elegant solution would be to use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module. Using `defaultdict` and moving the definition of `addlist`, you should look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listwords = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dictwords = {'111': "['a', 'a', 'b']", '112': "['b', 'a', 'b']"}
newdict = defaultdict(list)

for i in listwords:
    for k, x in dictwords.items():
        addlist= []
            if i in x:
                cont = 0
                cont = x.count(i)
                addlist.append(k)
                addlist.append(cont)
                newdict[i].append(addlist)
```

And printing `newdict` should give you something like this:

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [['111', 2], ['112', 1]], 'b': [['111', 1], ['112', 2]]})`

You can of course make the output more pretty for your purposes.

Comment: Good and clear solution, but please notice that you don't mention that 'c' has no references.

Comment: Yeah your right @AmitHaim, but I'm not sure why that's something that needs to mentioned in an answer? The user had a specific question concerning his code, which I provided feedback for. Unless stated otherwise, I'm assuming that's the extent of his problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Right now all the entries are referring to the same list, and you're mutating it.

```py
occurences = {}
for word in list_of_words:
    list_to_store = []
    for key, words in dict_of_words.items():
        list_to_store.append((key, words.count(word)))
    occurences[word] = list_to_store
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```py
occurences = {}
for word in list_of_words:
    occurences[word] = [(key, words.count(word))
                        for key, words in dict_of_words.items()]
```

You can also combine it with a dict comprehension:

```py
occurences = {
    word: [(key, words.count(word))
           for key, words in dict_of_words.items()]
    for word in list_of_words
}
```

And this looks much more concise.

Output code:

```py
for k, v in occurences.items():
    print(f"{k} -> {v}")
```

Output:

```
a -> [('111', 2), ('112', 1)]
b -> [('111', 1), ('112', 2)]
c -> [('111', 0), ('112', 0)]
```